# access mail inbox using python

Tags: python, email, exchange

I'd like to write a python script that access my email at work (it's accessible from anywhere). So, we're using a browser-based email client called OWA, here's a small documentation of that (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/owa/set-up-web-access)

The webpage for work email is something like (mail.something.com/owa/), then it asks for the credentials which I use to access my company's computer.

Things to note we don't have a POP3 or IMAP, we can access the email only through this domain and login with our credentials.

**So, I need to know what library do I have to use to access my email through the link (mail.something.com/owa/) to read my inbox and download attachments?**

Comment: Look for an API. You don't want to mess around with HTML.

Comment: Evolution can handle Exchange Server with `evolution-ews` Extension.

Comment: @Panki, perhaps you could tip me off to where I can probably find an API?

Comment: @pLumo I think (evolution-ews) isn't what I am looking for, i'd like to connect to my email using python as a start to read emails.

Comment: A very quick research on the www gave me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288546/connect-to-exchange-mailbox-with-python and https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/

Comment: @pLumo, I came across this post, howerver, it's not showing how it will connect to my work domain (mail.something.com/owa/)

Comment: That 'OWA' thing is powered by exchange, so @pLumos answer is actually what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my way of accessing and reading emails

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from exchangelib import Account, Configuration, Credentials, DELEGATE, Folder


def connect(SERVER, EMAIL, USERNAME, PASSWORD):
    """
    Get Exchange account cconnection with server
    """
    creds = Credentials(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
    config = Configuration(server=SERVER, credentials=creds)
    account = Account(primary_smtp_address=EMAIL, autodiscover=False, config=config, access_type=DELEGATE)

    for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:2]:
        print(item.subject, item.body, item.attachments)


def main():

    print(connect("mail.something.com", "email@xx.local", "userinActiveDirectory", "password"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```